# Convert a column of GeoJSON-like strings to geometry objects in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I have a column in a GeoPandas dataframe with strings like this one `'{type=Point, coordinates=[37.55, 55.71]}'` or this `'{type=MultiPoint, coordinates=[[37.6, 55.4]]}'`. It can be a polygon or any other geometry as well. Then there are a few points in the form of nested list. How can I transform it to the ordinary GeoPandas geometry objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`shapely.geometry.shape`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.geometry.shape) to convert geojson strings to shapely geometry.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape

df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda: row: shape(row['jsoncolumn']), axis=1)
```

Comment: It returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` and the debugger points at the line `geom_type = ob.get("type").lower()`

Comment: I see. It is not proper JSON, that is why. You can try to convert your string into JSON-like one and use `json.loads` before `shape` or somehow regenerate geometries manually. Maybe someone will know better way.

Comment: Yeah, I did it in my case but I probably didn't use the best method. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it as follows. Thanks to @martinfleis

```
# Add necessary shapes and keys
coordinates = 'coordinates'
type = 'type'
Point = 'Point'
MultiPoint = 'MultiPoint'
Polygon = 'Polygon'
MultiPolygon = 'MultiPolygon'
center='center'

df['geometry'] = df.geoData.apply(lambda x: shape(eval(x.replace('=',':'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

From this source : [on github](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/5a54fc4f1db06a66679e)

I built the following function :

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geojson
import json

def geojsonification(x):
    
    geom = x['geom']

    if type(geom) == dict:
        s = json.dumps(geom)
        s2 = geojson.loads(s)
        res = shape(s2)
        return res
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Which you can use as this :

```
gdf.geometry = gdf.apply(geojsonification, axis=1)
```